# How to defocus a cursor from an input text field in protractor

Tags: protractor, ui-automation, browser-automation

I have an input text field filled with date. I have to clear the date text and click cursor to somewhere on webpage or to some element to do other actions.

Now the problem is I am unable to move cursor to some other element or somewhere on webpage. Cursor remains on that input box once text is cleared

I have tried following ways:

1. mouseMove: I am trying to move cursor to somewhere on webpage and clicking it but not working.
2. blur() : used this one to loose the focus but not working.

   ```
   var input = element(by.css('input[placeholder = "Choose a date"]'))
   var someOtherElement = element(by.id('otherElement'));
   input.click().clear().then((function) {
   browser.actions().mouseMove(someOtherElement).click().perform();
   });
   ```

Actual: Once date text is cleared, cursor remains on the text input. it is not moving from that text box.

Expected: I wanna cursor loose the focus and move to some other element and click it so that I can do some other actions.

Comment: Would a tab keystroke suffice to shift focus from the field instead of a mouse click?

Comment: @DublinDev - 

I used below code then it is giving me error  "Cannot read property of TAB undefined"

            Input.click().clear().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);

or when I used below code then text is clearing and coming back again. code:

        Input.click().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);

Comment: I'm not clear on the expected manual behavior you are trying to verify. Can you confirm if this is correct? Field has default text "choose a date" which disappears when user clicks on the field. Then when users tabs or navigates to another field it remains clear?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any error stack for this? Would be great if you paste it here.
I am actually suspecting that someOtherElement does not exist or not clickable.

Can you give below snippet also a shot by making the function which have below code in it as async()?

```
var input = await element(by.css('input[placeholder = "Choose a date"]'));
var someOtherElement = await element(by.id('otherElement'));

await input.click().clear().then(() => {
   someOtherElement.click();
})
.then(() => console.log('finished'));
```